# How do I synchronously get the Facebook UID of the connected user in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook

I use iOS Facebook SDK 3.1. I am using  [FBSession's openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/class/FBSession#openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:) to connect the user to Facebook. After the user is connected, is there way to synchronously get the logged in user's UID? I am aware I can asynchronously get the UID with [FBRequestConnection's startForMeWithCompletionHandler:](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/class/FBRequestConnection#startForMeWithCompletionHandler:), but the asynchronousness complicates my flow and the extra HTTP request seems wasted to get something as simple as the UID.

Comment: Simple answer: You don't. Never do synchronous networking on iOS.

Comment: @StevenFisher I asked for a synchronous non-HTTP request to get the UID.

Comment: Ah, you mean that the Facebook SDK ought to be caching it somewhere? That makes more sense, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the asyncronousness complicates my flow

It's usually *easier* for the programmer to do things synchronously, but its usually *better* for the user to do things asynchronously.

> the extra HTTP request seems wasted to get something as simple as the UID

How long will that request take? 100 milliseconds? 1 second? 10 seconds? Answer: you have no way of knowing how long it'll take, and it could easily be 10 seconds or more in some cases. Do you really want to freeze your app for that long because you're too lazy to do things the right way? What will your users think? Do you care?

Comment: I didn't want to block the HTTP request that queries for the UID. I wanted to get the UID from memory through the Facebook SDK.